# RegexReplace in GoogleSheets To Find Multiple Strings

Tags: regex, google-sheets, substring

I have a string such as the following

```
bells<1@gmail.com>,bars<2@gmail.com>, ballots<3@gmail.com>
```

I would like to extract the e-mail addresses out of this string comma separated

Formula using is the following

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A7,"\<(.*?)\>","")
```

However, the results I get are the following and opposite of what I was expecting

```
bells,bars, ballots
```

This formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(A7,"\<(.*?)\>")` results in `1@gmail.com` just fine, but I want to get all three 3 instances.

Any help and explanation as to why the regex "<(.*?)>" isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^<]*<([^<>]*)>(,?)", "$1$2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/We2oWP/1). *Details*:

- `[^<]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`
- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` chars
- `>` - a `>` char
- `(,?)`  - Group 2: an optional `,` char.

`$1` and `$2` refer to the values captured with Group 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks this worked well and was able to add additional e-mails which worked as well.  Thanks for answering and the key for me was understanding how to use the capture groups in the regexreplace. Thanks again for the answer